# ¿Cómo obtener un string específico de un string-array?

Tags: android

**Descripción:**

La pregunta es corta. Tengo un string-array en mis **strings.xml** con 10 elementos. Me gustaría obtener el elemento número 5 de dicho array.

Con la siguiente línea de código, se puede obtener el array entero, pero yo lo que quiero es obtener solo un elemento del array:

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombre);
```

**Gracias por leer!**

Comment: Puedes hacer un ciclo for, para obtener la posicion del arreglo que necesites. Recorrerlo hasta array.size y luego obtener el String cuando sea igual a la posicion q necesitas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombre)[4];
```

Tomada de la siguiente [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161256/referencing-a-string-in-a-string-array-resource-with-xml) en inglés.

Aquí está un pequeño [ejemplo](https://github.com/israteneda/StackOverflow/tree/master/StringArray).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes almacenar el array definido en strings.xml dentro de un array de elementos tipo String ?

```
String[] nombres = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nombre);
```

y puedes acceder a sus elementos en base a su indice, en este caso para el quinto elemento usarias el indice 4, por ejemplo

```
String primerNombre = nombres[0];
String segundoNombreNombre = nombres[1];
String tercerNombre = nombres[2];
String cuartoNombre = nombres[3];
String quintoNombre = nombres[4];
```

de igual forma puedes realizar otras operaciones como iterar sobre el array para obtener todos sus elementos

```
for (String nombre: nombres) {           
       System.out.println(nombre); 
}
```